# How to upload powerpoint/word file through postman

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, postman

My main objective is to upload **.pptx/.docx/.pdf** file to Microsoft Sharepoint using Microsoft Graph API.
Am able to upload to simple text files using the below "PUT" request, where the content-type is **multipart/form-data**

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/{simple.txt}:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive-id%7D/root:/%7Bsimple.txt%7D:/content)

But for **.pptx/.docx/.pdf** files, although am getting response as **"200 ok"**, but no file is getting creating in sharepoint site document.

I have correctly configured **File type with "File"** as the key and selected the appropriate file in the value of the body of the request in postman.

Observation -> While uploading txt file, the response is "201 created" and the contents of the uploaded files is getting changed. For example, if the content was "Hello there". The upload file content is,

> ----------------------------404518839734975569926100
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="sample.txt"
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> Hello there
> ----------------------------404518839734975569926100--

Can someone explain what's going on here and how to upload pptx/doc/pdf file in sharepoint using MS Graph API's.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload the .docx file using Graph API in post man like this.

```
PUT drives/{drive-id}/root:/fileName.docx:/content
```

In Body, choose binary type.

[image]